# Fetch value of one of two buttons with same name but different value

Tags: jquery, html, button

I was trying to fetch the value of the one button out of many with the same name but different values as given in html code. How it is possible to get value of the button on which we click using jQuery?

```html
<html>
<input type="button" name="btn1" value="Button1" text="Button1">
<input type="button" name="btn1" value="Button2" text="Button2">
<input type="button" name="btn1" value="Button3" text="Button3">
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve] here using the stack snippet: `&lt;&gt;` in the editor  with effort and CODE not PICTURES of code

Answer (score 0):

Yo can get the `attribute` of type text from your `input button` and display it.

```js
$("input").click(function(){
  var value=$(this).attr("text");
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<input type="button" name="btn1" value="Button1" text="Button1">
<input type="button" name="btn1" value="Button2" text="Button2">
<input type="button" name="btn1" value="Button3" text="Button3">
</html>
```